# How to set the Id field of an ArrayStore (So that records can be looked up by the value of that field) in ExtJS 3

Tags: extjs, extjs-stores

I am having trouble with Ext.data.ArrayStore. I have one defined as so:

```
var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: [
        'myIdField',
        'myDataField'      
    ],
    idProperty: 'myIdField'
});

store.add(new store.recordType({
    myIdField: 'a',
    myDataField: 'SomeData'
}));
```

However, when I do

```
var myInsertedRecord = store.getById('a');
```

the value of myInsertedRecord is 'undefined'.

Am I misunderstanding how does the setting o the record id work?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.ArrayStore does not have an `idProperty`.
Try creating a Model, specifying the `idProperty` in the Model. Use that model to create your store.

Example:

```
Ext.define('MyData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['myIdField', 'myDataField'],
    idProperty: 'myIdField'
});


var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    model: 'MyData'
});

store.add({
    myIdField: 'a',
    myDataField: 'SomeData'
});


var myRecord = store.getById('a');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the app I'm working on uses ExtJS 3, so creating a model is not an option :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I'll answer it anyway ...

The issue is the way you are creating the new record to add to the store. Have a look at the [Ext.data.Record-static-method-create](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Record-static-method-create) function. You will see that it can take an optional ID parameter.

So, to make your above example work, you'll need to add the record to the store like so:

```
store.add(new store.recordType({
    myIdField: 'a',
    myDataField: 'SomeData'}, 'a'));
```

Notice the last 'a', that's where you apply the ID to the record.

After that, your added record will have an ID so `store.getById('a')` will work for you.